# Scanning php uploads in tmp directory with clamdscan fails

Tags: php, apache-http-server, permissions, anti-virus

I can't seem to get this thing to work, some permission problem maybe, but i can't even run clamdscan normally form console with root the result is always Permission denied. for example i create a file test.txt (eicar file) in /tmp and execute "clandscan /tmp/test.txt" in console logged in as root and i get "/tmp/test.txt: Access denied. ERROR ". The clamd demon is running with user clamav could that be the reason?
Now i want to scan the same file (/tmp/test.txt) via php , so i run (i have chowned the file to apache:apache )

```
$cmd="clamdscan /tmp/test.txt";
exec($cmd,$a,$b);
```

i get error 127 i try with the full path of the command /usr/bin/clamdscan i get error 126 (command is found but is not executable), this means that apache doesn't have the permission to execute /usr/bin/clamdscan ?
what could be the problem?

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/clamdcscan` have execute flag set? Root won't run a program if there's no execute mode on it.

Comment: yes it has +x set

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one but:

```
$cmd="clamdscan --fdpass /tmp/test.txt";
exec($cmd,$a,$b);
```

From the docs:
The --fdpass option sends a file descriptor to clamd rather than a path name, and avoids the need for the clamav user to be able to read everyone's files. As a result, the daemon should be able to run as the default clamav user in any scenario. 
...
Users who want to scan a file or directory should ask the clamd daemon to do it using the clamdscan --fdpass command